# What is the concept of limit to derivative?

Tags: limits, derivatives

Can someone explain me in intuition or as a concept how the limit of $\frac{∆T}{∆t}$ for $t \to 0$ can turn into derivative function of $\frac{∂T}{∂t}$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is explained in just about every introduction to calculus. Draw a picture showing a short chord on the graph that starts from the particular point where you want to find the derivative.

Comment: Take a look [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative).

Comment: This is the *definition* of the derivative. What else do you expect the derivative to be ?

Comment: It's not clear what you want explained.  Are you asking how can $\lim \frac {\Delta T}{\Delta t}$ can be known and evaluated at all?  Or are you asking we it if $\lim \frac{\Delta T}{\Delta t}$ and $\frac {\partial T}{\partial t}$ both give the same value?  If the latter, what do then what does $\frac {\partial T}{\partial t}$ mean? How was it defined?  Or do you mean specific formulas? Are you asking if $\frac {\partial T}{\partial t}$ is certain formulas for different $T$, then the answer is the formulas were *derived* to *BE* $\lim\frac{\Delta T}{\delta t}$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the very definition of a derivative is defined in terms of a limit:

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x + \Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$

You can understand the intuition behind this definition by analyzing the *tangent line problem*. This problem is essentially the problem of finding the rate of change at a certain single point on a curve. We can approximate the rate of change over an interval using secant lines:

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

But this is over an *interval*. We want a single point.

Let's say we want to find the rate of change at a point, $a$. Let's try to rewrite the secant line equation in terms of $a$.

$$\frac{f(a + \Delta a)-f(a)}{\Delta a}$$

If you didn't know, $\Delta$ is the size of our interval. We want the size of our interval to become infinitesimally small. How do we do that? Limits! And this is how we arrive at our definition.